# Pass pan gesture between a swipable cell and UIPageViewController (Snapchat style)

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I'd like the `UIPageViewController` to start scrolling only once a swipeable cell has reached a certain position. Just like the gesture needed to get to a text chat on Snapchat.

Thanks!